# How to extend Javascript Prototype?

Tags: javascript, overriding, prototype, extend

I instantiate a function from my template with

```
new Product.Image({
        "title": document.querySelector('#image-title')
    });
```

But now I need to extend "Product.Image" e.g. with "Product.BetterImage"

```
new Product.BetterImage({
        "title": document.querySelector('#better-image-title')
    });
```

My original class starts like this:

```
Product.Image = function (options) {
  //do something
}
Product.Image.prototype = new Product.Data();
```

Now I tried to copy it to extend "Product.Image":

```
Product.BetterImage = function (options) {
  //do something
}
Product.BetterImage.prototype = new Product.Image();
```

But when I call my template to initiate it I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Product.BetterImage is not a constructor
```

What am I missing here or what have done wrong?
Can anyone explain me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with javascript inheritance and prototype delegation - see this good MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

This part of your code is not needed and causing the problem:

```
Product.Image = function (options) {
  //do something
}
Product.Image.prototype = new Product.Data();
```

The right way to do this is to create your 'Product' class and then add directly to its Prototype, like so:

```
var Product = function(data) {
  this.data = data;
}

Product.prototype.image = function() {
   // return data here
}

Product.prototype.better = function(){
  // add stuff here
}

Product.prototype.betterImage = function(){
  // add more stuff here
}
```

then to create an instance or instantiate your class you use can use the 'new' keyword

```
var myProduct = new Product(data);
```

Comment: But how can I extend "Product.Image" with "Product.BetterImage"? I want to use all methods from "Product.Image" in my "Product.BetterImage" but override one or two methods with it.

Comment: In the code above, whatever methods you put in betterImage will be there, if they are not they will fall back to the original Product.prototype.
if you want to extend a prototype of product, its probably time to make a new class... did you read the docs? There are several ways to do this. hint: look at the docs, find the example at the bottom - its exactly what youre looking for